# Valores fixados em cima do gráfico AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Tenho alguns gráficos com [angular-charts](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) onde os valores só aparecem quando passo o mouse por cima:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que esses valores ficassem fixos em cima de cada respectiva área do gráfico. Já procurei na [documentação](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration) uma forma de resolver esse problema e não encontrei nada.

Teria alguma maneira de fixar esses valores?

Comment: Também estou a procura exatamente disto e não consigo encontrar resposta. Já fazem 2 anos... Você tem alguma novidade?

Comment: @WesleyRedfield Não encontrei a solução e optei por deixar dessa forma, porém já faz muito tempo. Pode ser que nas versões mais novas da lib essa função esteja implementada.